# Relationship between Hankel Function and Hypergeometric Function

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to evaluate this function:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{p^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{p^2+y^2}}dy$$

Using contour integration, this integral should be possible. But using the section 6.677 of I. S.Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (9th integral) I have found the answer to be

$$- i \pi \text{H}^{(2)}_0(kp)$$

Mathematica evaluates this integral to be

$$-2 \text{Hypergeometric0F1Regularized}^{(1,0)}\left(1,-\frac{1}{4} k^2 p^2\right)+(-2 \log (k p)-i \pi +\log (4)) J_0(k p)$$

Superscript $(1,0)$ indicates that the function is differentiated wrt the first parameter of the function.

Now, mathematica evaluates these expressions to be the same (it is disappointing that mathematica failed to find the simpler notation using the Hankel function)

I am curious if anyone has any explanation as to how (perhaps even why) this identity holds.

Comment: it seems you need to show that [$H_0^{(2)} (x) = \lim_{ \alpha \to 0}\frac{J_{-\alpha} (x) - e^{\alpha \pi i} J_\alpha (x)}{- i \sin (\alpha \pi)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions:_H.CE.B1.281.29.2C_H.CE.B1.282.29) and [$J_\alpha(x)=\frac{(\frac{x}{2})^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}  \;_0F_1 (\alpha+1; -\tfrac{x^2}{4})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Relation_to_hypergeometric_series) possibly from the differential equation definitions

Comment: I probably will not be going through with the calculations, but this is enough for me to see how such a relation might be possible. Thanks.

Comment: TO grdgfgr,    Sir, kindly peruse the integral given *at serial no. 11 under section 8.421* of *Table of Integrals by Gradshteyn and Ryjhik* that $H_0^1(x)=\frac{-i}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp i [\sqrt{x^2+t^2}]}{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}\, dt$, So,in view of this,  the answer of your integral would be $H_0^1(kp)$.I am also studying the same kind of integral and I am looking for the details proof .Sir, would you kindly suggest me any reference for this case...